# Is it possible to send Bitcoin without the passphrase to the wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, private-key

I’ve been getting back into cryptocurrency lately, and I’ve found one of my  old wallet.dat files with a very small amount of BTC. Unfortunately, I created a random password of characters and put it on a piece of paper, which I have lost by mistake. **Is there any way I can send the Bitcoin to my other used wallet without the passphrase**, such as by finding the private keys with PyWallet and using them? I’m using Bitcoin Core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you need the password to spend any money in the wallet.

The keys are encrypted with the password you provided.